# Open a nova-api route to the public?

Tags: laravel-nova

Given a resource of Offer, I'd like to harness the built in Nova API functionality by opening up any GET request to /nova-api/offers in order to prototype a Vue app.

Is there a simple/clever way to do this? I imagine worst case scenario would be to create a custom guard.